# How to install luasql on Linux Ubuntu 16?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, lua, torch

Thanks to the help of the StackOverflow community, I was able to correctly install luasql on my [computer running Linux CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149280/how-to-install-luasql-on-linux-centos-7).

Now I have a similar problem on Linux Ubuntu 16.
I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -y install lua-sql-postgres
sudo apt-get -y install lua-sql-postgres-dev
sudo luarocks install luasql-postgres
```

And here's the error I get from the system:

```
Installing https://rocks.moonscript.org/luasql-postgres-2.3.5-2.rockspec...
Using https://rocks.moonscript.org/luasql-postgres-2.3.5-2.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode

Error: Could not find expected file libpq-fe.h, or libpq-fe.h for PGSQL -- you may have to install PGSQL in your system and/or pass PGSQL_DIR or PGSQL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luasql-postgres PGSQL_DIR=/usr/local
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Please install `libpq-dev`  : The file is in `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h` http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/libpq-dev/filelist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by @Knud Larsen:

First, you need to install `libpq-dev`.

If it was installed successfully, you can see the file `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h`

After that execute the command:

```
sudo luarocks PGSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/postgresql/ install luasql-postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

---

Please install the package `libpq-dev` :

The file `libpq-fe.h` is in `/usr/include/postgresql/` http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/libpq-dev/filelist

Comment: Thanks. I installed `libpq-dev` but nothing changed... any other idea?